# Client Authentication with node js mosca broker

Tags: node.js, mqtt

We are using node.js' [Mosca broker](http://www.mosca.io/) module for one of our applications. We are planning to add client authentication with a certificate on the  broker side but I'm unable to find any configuration or settings in Mosca has for client authentication.

In the [Mosquito broker](http://mosquitto.org/) configuration, the file has one property and requires that the certificate be true. Is there anything similar to that in Mosca?

Comment: Update: Mosca Broker now supports client authentication.

Answer (score 4):

[According to the documentation](http://mcollina.github.io/mosca/docs/lib/server.js.html#authenticate), one can authenticate a client using

```
server.authenticate = function (client, username, password, callback) {
   // To authenticate
   callback(null, true);
   // To reject
   callback(null, false);
}
```

You can also override this function to be able to use certificate-based authentication or whatever else you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But one more question arises here is  If the client is passing certificate then what is way to get the same at mosca broker side.Like in node js http request req.connection.getPeerCertificate() will give me the client certificate and then I use the same to check the client authenticity.

Comment: @vidyak That will depend entirely on how you're sending the certificate. MQTT =/= HTTP. I'm not really familiar with the protocol, but I'd consider creating an issue on the Mosca Github page if you need further help.